# sql IF statement in prepared mysqli statement

Tags: sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have reviewed this several times and can't find a reason why it shouldn't work hopefully someone can reveal what I'm missing here's my prepared statement.

When performing a `var_dump` on `$query` directly after initializing the prepared statement it returns false.

```
$query = $link->prepare("IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM banned WHERE ipAddr=? OR uid=?)) THEN UPDATE banned SET isBanned='1', ipAddr=?, uid=?, bannedAt=NOW(), reason=? WHERE ipAddr=? OR uid=? ELSE INSERT INTO banned (isBanned, ipAddr, uid, bannedAt, reason) VALUES('1', ?, ?, NOW(), ?) END IF");
$query->bind_param("sisissisis", $details['IP'], $details['uid'], $details['IP'], $details['uid'], $details['reason'], $details['IP'], $details['uid'], $details['IP'], $details['uid'], $details['reason']);
```

Table structure

```
banned
------
id,  uid, ipAddr, bannedAt, reason, isBanned
```

**Note: if this is not the best way to achieve the same result then please offer a suggestion**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` statement is not supported in prepared statements in Mysql. For full list of supported statements and more read *[SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)*

IMHO you have several options

1. Try using `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `REPLACE`. You'll need to have correct `UNIQUE` index(indices) for it.
2. Wrap you code into a stored procedure

A stored procedure might look look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_add_banned(IN aIP VARCHAR(15), IN aId INT, aReason VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM banned WHERE ipAddr=aIP OR uid=aId)) THEN 
      UPDATE banned 
         SET isBanned='1', ipAddr=aIP, uid=aId, bannedAt=NOW(), reason=aReason 
       WHERE ipAddr=aIP OR uid=aId;
  ELSE 
      INSERT INTO banned (isBanned, ipAddr, uid, bannedAt, reason) 
      VALUES('1', aIP, aId, NOW(), aReason);
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

*Adjust data types for `IN` parameters as they defined in your `banned` table*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3149/4)** demo.

And your php part will look like

```
$query = $link->prepare('CALL sp_add_banned(?, ?, ?)');
$query->bind_param('sis', $details['IP'], $details['uid'], $details['reason']);
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL

> IF EXISTS

syntax only works in a store procedure.

You could create a Store Procedure, then called it from your code for validating and Insert or update.

For your reference: [mySql If Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)

And if you are using 'IF' function on SELECT Queries, it have a different syntax. Here is the [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ON DUPLICATE` syntax.

Here is documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html